# Adding a file to .gitignore with a $ in its filename?

Tags: git, glob, gitignore

How do you `.gitignore` a file with a `$` in its filename?

Does it need to be escaped somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape `$`

Add into `.gitignore` this

```
foo$bar
```

to ignore `foo$bar` file

NB:
By the way you should use `\` to escape

```
foo\$bar
```

will work but this is not necessary

Comment: Dollar-sign isn't special here, so it doesn't *need* escaping, but adding one doesn't hurt either (except maybe to confuse a human reader).

Comment: Note that if you are trying to test your ignore rule in Powershell, you'll have to use the the backtick "\`" character to escape the $. Eg.: `git check-ignore -v -- foo\`$bar`.